# About result of two polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $K$ be a field and $f,g \in K[t]$ s.t. $\deg(f)=n,\; \deg(g)=m$. Then there exist two polynomials with degree less or equal than $n$, respectively $m$ s.t. $fp=gq$.

I tried using Euclidean Division but it didn't work, the hint is using the resultant but I can't see which polynomials I must apply the resultant.

All the hints or any help will be thanked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d = \gcd(f,g)$. Write $f=dq$ and $g=dp$. Then $fp=lcm(f,g)=gq$.